# Больше vs. более

Tags: значения

Sometimes I am not sure and a little confused when to use `больше` and when to use `более`, can somebody explain it to me? For example which sentence is grammatically right?:

```
Надо больше пить.
```

or

```
Надо более пить.
```

Comment: Answer in russian: http://rus.stackexchange.com/a/39604/176629 In your example the correct form is "Надо больше пить".

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In some cases Больше/более are used interchangeably, but they also have different meanings.

A. Больше and более (bookish) used interchangeably:

1. больше/более (exceeding the quantity mentioned); более is bookish.

> Возможно ждать больше/более часа (It is possible to wait for more than an hour.)

> Стоит больше/более трех рублей. (It costs more than three roubles.)

2. Idioms:
   **Больше всего/более всего** (above all, most of all)

> Более всего ему сейчас следует опасаться простуды. (Above all, he should now be wary of catching a cold.)

**Больше того,/более того** (moreover, more importantly, even better, even worse, worse than that) indicates a transition to an additional, often more important, consideration.

> Ваша деятельность бесполезна; более того, она даже вредна. (Your activity is useless; worse than that, it's harmful.)

> Умен, более того, талантлив. (He is clever, and moreover, gifted.)

**Больше чем/ более чем** (more than, very, to a high extent)

> Более чем интересно. (It's more than [just] interesting.)

> Ваше поведение более чем возмутительно. (Your behavior is more than [just] outrageous.)

**Не больше чем / не более чем** (only)

> Это не более чем игра. (It's only a game.)

**Ни больше ни меньше как / Не более и не менее, как** (neither more nor less than; exactly)

> Речь идет не более и не менее, как о франко-германском соглашении. (It is nothing more and nothing less than a Franco-German agreement.)

> Опоздал ни больше ни меньше как на час. (I was late by an hour, no more and no less.)

B. Больше

1. Больше - далее (**not again, no more [extending into the future]**)

> Больше туда не ходи. (Don't go there anymore.)

> Больше не буду (I won't do it anymore.)

> Больше нет вопросов? (Any questions?)

Более is archaic in this context.

2. **comparative of большой or много**

> Та комната больше. (That room is bigger.)

> У него больше игрушек, чем у меня. (He has more toys than I do.)

> Надо тренироваться больше. (You should exercise more.)

3. mostly, mainly

> Шли больше лесом. (We walked more in the forest.)

4. **И больше ничего** ("and nothing else"/"and that's all")

> Делай, что говорят, и больше ничего. (Do what they say and nothing else.)

C. Более

1.**forms the comparative** of adjectives and adverbs

> более подвижные, более спокойный, более важно

2. Idioms:
   **Более или менее** ("more or less", "to some extent") [неправильно более-менее].

> Более или менее понятно. (It's more or less clear.)

**Тем более** (especially) — emphatic

> Климат здесь вредный, тем более для ребёнка. (The climate here is harmful, especially for a child.)

**тем более (что)**. (moreover because)

> Остаёмся дома, тем более собирается гроза. (We're staying at home, especially since a thunderstorm is about to come.)

**всё более и более** (more and more) - about something increasing or decreasing

> Гул всё более и более утихал. (The rumbling subsided more and more.)

> Отношения становились всё более и более натянутыми. (The relationship became more and more strained.)

About your examples:

Надо больше пить. Here, больше is the comparative of много (quantity)

Answer (score 0):

этот стул больше - this chair is bigger - size or amount
этот стул более удобный - this chair is more comfortable - comparison

Comment: Do you mean, size or amount is expressed in _больше никогда_? There's no comparison in _он больше, чем ты_?

Comment: I agree, I'm not a linguist, just common sense,  
"больше никогда" implicitly means no more times of some action,  
"больше чем ты" also sounds like amount, to compare persons it's more correctly to use exact adjectives e.g. старше/моложе, выше/ниже, толще/худее/более худой

Answer (score 0):

Often you just need to learn a specific cases of usage, there are some idioms, like @V.V. said. But generally you can remember that "более" is more emotional and dramatic form of "больше". So when you are unsure which word to use in a sentence: just imagine whether you can say the sentence in a calm, rational state of mind, if yes - use "больше", if no - use "более".

In your example "You need to drink more" can be said by a doctor, emotionally indifferent to your problems. So you need to say "Надо болЬШЕ пить".